# merge two pandas series in a datagrame without explicitly using keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge, series

I have tow class 'pandas.core.series.Series':

"dist"

```
-9999      110160.551216
-9999.1    121535.209511
-9999.2    124808.195632
-9999.3    132015.091440
-9999.4    129312.118880
-9999.5    119686.351986
-9999.6    110988.442182
-9999.7    104297.914620
dtype: float64
```

and "data"

```
-9999      0.0
-9999.1    1.6
-9999.2    0.0
-9999.3    NaN
-9999.4    0.0
-9999.5    0.0
-9999.6    NaN
-9999.7    NaN
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```

I would like to merge them in a dataframe in order to remove nan columns.
I have tried different things:

```
new = pd.concat([dist, data],axis=1)
```

but this creates only long variable.

```
new = pd.concat([dist, data],axis=0)
```

but this create a long row as:

```
,-9999,-9999.1,-9999.2,-9999.3,-9999.4,-9999.5,-9999.6,-9999.7,-9999,-9999.1,-9999.2,-9999.3,-9999.4,-9999.5,-9999.6,-9999.7
0,110160.55121567169,121535.20951103275,124808.19563190002,132015.0914399207,129312.11887963412,119686.35198568225,110988.44218156513,104297.91462028676,0.0,1.6,0.0,,0.0,0.0,,
```

This is what I expect:

```
-9999,  -9999.1,    -9999.2,    -9999.3,    -9999.4,    -9999.5,    -9999.6,    -9999.7
110160.551215672,   121535.209511033,   124808.1956319, 132015.091439921, 129312.118879634, 119686.351985682,   110988.442181565,   104297.914620287
0,1.6,0,,0,,,0
```

This should allow me to remove some columns according to nan.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
(pd.concat([dist, data],axis=1)
   .reset_index().T
   .replace('Na',0).to_csv('filename.csv',index=False,header=False))
```

OR

```
(dist.reset_index().astype({'index':'float'})
     .merge(data.reset_index().astype({'index':'float'}),on='index').T
     .replace('Na',0)
     .to_csv('filename.csv',index=False,header=False))
```

Comment: It seems not working.  It is still a long string but it is in two rows. filename is correct but not the new dataframe.  If I put new = pd.concat([dist, data],axis=1).reset_index().T  I have still a series with only index=0 and column 0

Comment: yes, both. I have also tried to convert them to dataframe with     dfr_dist = pd.DataFrame(), dfr_dist['1'] =  dist, dfr_data = pd.DataFrame() dfr_data['2'] =  data but I have the same problems.

Comment: @diedro `reset_index()` is converting them to dataframe...pls try running the above method with your series(you initial data)

Comment: ok.  I will try. Maybe the problem is that both  dataframes are arguments of a funtion and that could change something.  I have not post the full code in order to not create misunderstanding but I could post it, what do you think?

Comment: @diedro maybe try first If not work then post

Comment: they do not work. The first create a data frame with index and columns with same names. The second gives me "You are trying to merge on int64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat".

Comment: not working. I think that the problem is now related to the fact that dist and data are now the output of the function that I have set-up. As a consequence, data as a different structure. Index are now columns.

Comment: @diedro ohh I think someone other from the community can help....As both methods working on my side and as you said: As a consequence, data as a different structure. Index are now columns so I think you have to adopt code according to your need...Since I don't know what function is doing and returning

Comment: what do you think about posting the entire code?

Comment: @diedro idk...but with the given series both are working well

Comment: new question? Could I modify this one?

Comment: @diedro it's upto you....I don't mind If you make change in this question as well **:)**

Comment: I prefer to open another one due to the title of this one.

Comment: @diedro btw you can also make changes in title